# Is it possible to generate a URL to a product review with TrustPilot?

Tags: trustpilot

Service reviews can be linked using their ID, such as https://www.trustpilot.com/reviews/5cf7f376b055990650f3c24c where 5cf7f376b055990650f3c24c is the ID for the review.

I see no way of doing this for product reviews. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, product reviews are not currently published at Trustpilot's main website. They are only available at Trustboxes - the widgets you can embed in your own website.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for the response, Tomasz!